# Updating the file text streamreader or streamwriter

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io

I have one file with questions. and when I press a button it skips to the next unsolved question.

I want to do an algorithm that when I press the button it delete the line of the current question in the Question FILE

Like I have 10 questions. I answer the first and I skip the other. when I am at the final question and I press skip I want to go to the second question. I want to delete the line of the solved question.

How can I do this?

this is what I tried

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Label[,] answerLabel = new Label[1, 3];

    StreamReader question = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\intrebari.txt");
    StreamReader answer1 = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\raspuns1.txt");
    StreamReader answer2 = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\raspuns2.txt");
    StreamReader answer3 = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\raspuns3.txt");
    StreamReader goodAnswer = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\raspunsbun.txt");

    int answersNo;
    int currentQuestion;

    int totalNo;
    bool[] Checked = new bool[26];
    int score;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        totalNo = 26;
        answersNo = 0;
        currentQuestion = 0;

        score = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                answerLabel[i, j] = new Label();
                answerLabel[i, j].Left = 50;
                answerLabel[i, j].AutoSize = false;
                answerLabel[i, j].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                answerLabel[i, j].Width = 500;
                answerLabel[i, j].Height = 45;
                answerLabel[i, j].Top = 200 +j * 50;
                answerLabel[i, j].BackColor = Color.White;
                this.Controls.Add(answerLabel[i, j]);
            }

        label1.Text = question.ReadLine();
        answerLabel[0, 0].Text = answer1.ReadLine();
        answerLabel[0, 1].Text = answer2.ReadLine();
        answerLabel[0, 2].Text = answer3.ReadLine();

        answerLabel[0, 0].Click += new EventHandler(answer1_Click);
        answerLabel[0, 1].Click += new EventHandler(answer2_Click);
        answerLabel[0, 2].Click += new EventHandler(answer3_Click);

        for (int i = 0; i < totalNo; i++)
        {
            Checked[i] = false;
        }



    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // verifica
    {
        Checked[currentQuestion] = true;

        if (answerLabel[0, 0].BackColor == Color.Yellow && answerLabel[0, 1].BackColor == Color.White && answerLabel[0, 2].BackColor == Color.White)
        {
            if (File.ReadLines(Application.StartupPath + "\\raspunsbun.txt").ElementAt(currentQuestion) == answerLabel[0, 0].Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("bravo");
                score++;
                //MessageBox.Show(score.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ai gresit!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (answerLabel[0, 1].BackColor == Color.Yellow && answerLabel[0, 0].BackColor == Color.White && answerLabel[0, 2].BackColor == Color.White)
            {
                if (File.ReadLines(Application.StartupPath + "\\raspunsbun.txt").ElementAt(currentQuestion) == answerLabel[0, 1].Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("bravo");
                    score++;
                    //MessageBox.Show(score.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ai gresit!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (answerLabel[0, 2].BackColor == Color.Yellow && answerLabel[0, 1].BackColor == Color.White && answerLabel[0, 0].BackColor == Color.White)
                {
                    if (File.ReadLines(Application.StartupPath + "\\raspunsbun.txt").ElementAt(currentQuestion) == answerLabel[0, 2].Text)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("bravo");
                        score++;
                       // MessageBox.Show(score.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("ai gresit!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (answersNo < totalNo - 1)
        {
            do
            {
                if (currentQuestion < totalNo - 1)
                {
                    currentQuestion++;
                    MessageBox.Show(currentQuestion.ToString());
                    label1.Text = question.ReadLine();
                    answerLabel[0, 0].Text = answer1.ReadLine();
                    answerLabel[0, 1].Text = answer2.ReadLine();
                    answerLabel[0, 2].Text = answer3.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentQuestion = 0;
                    question.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                    question.DiscardBufferedData();
                    answer1.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                    answer1.DiscardBufferedData();
                    answer2.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                    answer2.DiscardBufferedData();
                    answer3.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                    answer3.DiscardBufferedData();

                }
            }
            while (Checked[currentQuestion] == false);

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ati terminat testul !");
        }

        answersNo++;

    }

    private void answer1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        answerLabel[0, 0].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    private void answer2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        answerLabel[0, 1].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    private void answer3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        answerLabel[0, 2].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //sterge raspunsul
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                answerLabel[i, j].BackColor = Color.White;
            }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //raspunde mai tarziu 


        if (answersNo < totalNo - 1)
        {
            do
            {
                if (currentQuestion < totalNo - 1)
                {
                    currentQuestion++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentQuestion = 0;
                    question.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                    question.DiscardBufferedData();
                    answer1.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                    answer1.DiscardBufferedData();
                    answer2.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                    answer2.DiscardBufferedData();
                    answer3.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                    answer3.DiscardBufferedData();
                }
            }
            while (Checked[currentQuestion] == true);

            label1.Text = question.ReadLine();
            answerLabel[0, 0].Text = answer1.ReadLine();
            answerLabel[0, 1].Text = answer2.ReadLine();
            answerLabel[0, 2].Text = answer3.ReadLine();
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: need more `clarification`,`code` and `template of your questions file`.

Comment: I posted what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what you are trying to achieve by deleting the question line for line.
I expect that you want the user to continue the test at the next question where he ended up previously?

I suggest on close of application to write out all unanswered questions to a temp file using:

```
Files.WriteAllLine(tempFile, unansweredQuestion[]);
```

And replace the question file with the temp file:

```
File.Delete("questions.txt");
File.Move(tempFile, "questions.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using XML to store your questions and then use LINQ to XML to load, organize, and delete questions as needed. [Here](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/10/understanding-c-simple-linq-to.html) is a great article that includes many LINQ to XML examples. And if you're new to XML W3Schools has some great XML tutorials [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/).